# Looking at this site, what can i do to get two Excel Web Access WP's next to eachother?

Tags: sharepoint-server, page-layout, space-usage

I've added two excel web parts. On the top one I set the width to 550 pixels. There's a ton of empty space and a client wants me to be able to add another one directly to the right.

So even thought the web part's width is 550, the white space, denoted by my strange box, is still taken up. I've tried multiple columns, but the "Test1" web part is on the far left making the page look odd.

Thanks in advance, long time lurker!

[image: A picture of the site]

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert table with two columns and then insert Excel WP into each column.

Comment: I've thought about that. So tho issue i have; there's alot of other content on the page in question. The page template was just the single column. If i add another column it makes the page extra wide. Also the top excel viewer stay against the left margin, making it far way from the other.

Comment: Okay i lied. I mistook table for column from the page layout. Raf. I thin you just solved my problem. I didn't think I'd be able to find a no code solution. Thanks. A. Ton.

Comment: Dear @EvanLH in case of I solved your problem could you please mark it as an answer?